How to upload multipart files to aws s3 bucket using spring boot
The error current request is not a multipart request occurs
2024-12-21T15:33:28.898+05:30 ERROR 3312 --- [fileupload] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service()
for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request] with root cause
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValueInternal(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:213) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:196) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
enter code here
[this is the error in postman]
{
    "timestamp": "2024-12-21T10:03:29.001+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/s3/upload"
}

i confgured s3Client in S3ClientConfig class. with credencials stored in application.yml file.
@Configuration
public class S3ClientConfig {

    @Value("${aws.s3.region}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${aws.s3.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${aws.s3.secretKey}")
    private String secretAccessKey;

    @Bean

     S3Client s3Client() {

        S3Client s3client = S3Client.builder()
                .region(Region.of(region))
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretAccessKey)))
                .forcePathStyle(true)
                .build();

        return s3client;
    }

}

here is my S3Service class looks like
package com.dimuthu.fileupload.service;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectResponse;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class S3Service {
    @Autowired
    private S3Client s3Client;

    public PutObjectResponse putObject(String bucketName, String key, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        log.info("Uploading file: {} to bucket: {} with key: {}", file.getOriginalFilename(), bucketName, key);
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("upload-", file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            file.transferTo(tempFile);
            PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.putObject(req -> req.bucket(bucketName).key(key),
                    RequestBody.fromFile(tempFile.toPath()));
            log.info("File uploaded successfully with ETag: {}", response.eTag());
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error uploading file: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            tempFile.delete();
        }
    }

}

and this is the my rest controller . i add consumes mediatype.ALL_VALUE
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class UploadControlller {

    @Value("${aws.s3.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;

    @Autowired
    private S3Service s3Service;

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/s3/upload", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploadfile") MultipartFile file){
        try {
            String key = "uploads/" + file.getOriginalFilename();
            s3Service.putObject(bucketName, key, file);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("" + e.getStackTrace());
        }

    } 
}


Please read: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
